# Display multiple images on scrollview by using DKImagePickerController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview

I would like to display multiple images on scrollview when user selected images with DKImagePickerController [github](https://github.com/zhangao0086/DKImagePickerController).
Here is my code but images don't appear. Anyone can tell what's wrong?
Thank you in advance!

```
    var picker = DKImagePickerController()
    var imagesArray = [Any]()

     @IBAction func pickPhoto(_ sender: Any) {

            picker.maxSelectableCount = 10
            picker.showsCancelButton = true
            picker.allowsLandscape = false
            picker.assetType = .allPhotos

            self.present(picker, animated: true)

            picker.didSelectAssets = { (assets: [DKAsset]) in

                self.imagesArray.append(assets)

                for i in 0..<self.imagesArray.count {

                    let imageView = UIImageView()
                    imageView.image = self.imagesArray[i] as? UIImage
                    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
                    let xposition = self.view.frame.width * CGFloat(i)
                    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: xposition, y: 330, width: self.scrollView.frame.width, height: 170)
                    self.scrollView.contentSize.width = self.scrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(i * 1)
                    self.scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
                }

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of displaying images to scrollView, you can add that images in array  and reload the collectionView/TableView..

as I did it here in collectionView

```
func showImagePicker() {
    let pickerController = DKImagePickerController()
    self.previewView?.isHidden = false
    pickerController.assetType = .allPhotos
    pickerController.defaultAssetGroup = .smartAlbumUserLibrary
    pickerController.didSelectAssets = { (assets: [DKAsset]) in
        if  assets.count>0
        {
            for var i in 0 ... assets.count-1 {
                assets[i].fetchOriginalImage(true, completeBlock: { (image, info) in
                        self.abc.append(image)
                })
            }
        }
        self.previewView?.reloadData()
    }
    self.present(pickerController, animated: true) {}
}
```

Here abc :`[UIImage]` and previewView? : `UICollectionView`
 and in collection delegate methods:

```
public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return self.abc.count
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    var cell: UICollectionViewCell?
    var imageView: UIImageView?

    cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CellImage", for: indexPath)
    imageView = cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(1) as? UIImageView
    if let cell = cell, let imageView = imageView
    {
        let tag = indexPath.row + 1
        cell.tag = tag
        imageView.image = self.abc[indexPath.row]
    }
    return cell!
}
```

Comment: @Daibaku let me know if this answer was helpful to you or not!

Comment: Thank you for the answer!! I would like images to be like instagram with page control. So if user picked 10 photos then display those and scroll horizontally with page control. Is that possible with collectionview?

Comment: @Daibaku if u find this answer helpful plz upvote it nd mark as correct 
nd about your question :: yes we can enable pagination in collectionView
for more like instagram you can use  ImageSlideShow github (https://github.com/zvonicek/ImageSlideshow) for ease in code by using for loop in your array

Comment: Thank you so much I'll try it out after I got to home!! Thank you again:)